# Перенос строки в коде

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть код

```html
let elemmenuitemli = document.querySelectorAll('.fa');
let sidemenu = document.querySelector('#sidemenu');

elemmenuitemli.addEventListener("onmouseenter", checkitem);
elemmenuitemli.addEventListener("onmouseleave", checkitem);


function checkitem() {
    if sidemenu.classList.contains("active")
    {
        /* Удаление меню ul*/
        sidemenu.innerHTML='
        /* Сворачивание меню ul */
          <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  </li>
  ';

    }
    else {
        /* Удаление меню ul*/
        sidemenu.innerHTML="<li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Техника для кухни</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Бытовая техника для дома</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Ноутбуки и компьютеры</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>    
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
    <a href="" class="nestedblock">Комплектующие</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>    
  </li>
  </li>";
        sidemenu.classList.add('active');
        /* Разворачивание меню ul */
    }
}
```

Каким образом в ветви `else` значение свойства `sidemenu.innerHTML` - строку можно записать в одну строку?

Comment: А зачем в одну строку?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский такое ощущение, что при переводе на другую строку закрывающая кавычка не работает.

Comment: После редактирования вопроса я вижу, что у вас проблема в том, что двойные кавычки находятся в двойных кавычках. Либо внутри используйте одинарные (или экранирование - обратный слэш), либо всю конструкцию оберните в одинарные

Comment: А лучше, в таком случае, используйте подход из моего ответа

Comment: ну что, ответ помог?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нахожусь на этапе проверки. В случае правильности ответа обязательно проголосую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я вижу, что у вас проблема в том, что двойные кавычки находятся в двойных кавычках. Либо внутри используйте одинарные (или экранирование: обратный слэш), либо всю конструкцию оберните в одинарные.

---

Подход, который получше:

Если вам надо вывести форматированный `html`, а в кавычках это невозможно сделать, то используйте шаблонные строки:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

https://learn.javascript.ru/es-string

Они позволяют и вставлять переменные внутрь, а также сохраняют форматирование `html` в таком виде, в котором написаны:

```js
let html = `
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>test1</li>
        <li>test2</li>
        <li>test3</li>
    </ul>
</div>`;

console.log(html);
```